# How to get type metada from typescript compiler api

Tags: typescript, types, compiler-construction, metadata

I need to get information about the types in `lib.dom.d.ts` so I can check what methods and properties are available in all the different HTML types programmatically.

I mean types like `HTMLInputElement` or `HTMLDivElement`, etc...

I have `typescript` 5.2.2

This is what I'm trying to right now

```js
function getTypeInfoForHTMLTag(typeName: string): void {
  const program = ts.createProgram([], {
    lib: ['lib.dom.d.ts'],
  });
  const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();

  const inputElementVar = ts.factory.createVariableDeclaration(
    'myElement',
    undefined, // Optional type annotation, you can specify the type here
    ts.factory.createTypeReferenceNode(typeName, [])
  );

  // Create a variable statement with the inputElementVar
  const variableStatement = ts.factory.createVariableStatement(
    undefined, // Optional modifiers
    ts.factory.createVariableDeclarationList([inputElementVar], ts.NodeFlags.Let)
  );

  const typeProperties = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(inputElementVar).getProperties();

  console.log('Type properties for HTMLElement:');
  for (const property of typeProperties) {
    console.log(property.escapedName);
  }
}

getTypeInfoForHTMLTag('HTMLInputElement');
```